# Yocto build failed while upgrading to pulseaudio 12.0

Tags: upgrade, yocto, webos, pulseaudio

I have never worked with Yocto before, have a chance of upgrading the pulseaudio from 9.0 to 12.0 for webos.
However when I am using the 12.0's pulseaudio.inc file, made changes as per my requirement, i am facing the following error during packaging.

```
ERROR: pulseaudio-12.0-12-r20pulseaudio_v12_14Nov do_package_qa: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: pulseaudio-misc path '/work/sa8155-webos-linux/pulseaudio/12.0-12-r20pulseaudio_v12_14Nov/packages-split/pulseaudio-misc/usr/lib/libpulse.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: pulseaudio-misc path '/work/sa8155-webos-linux/pulseaudio/12.0-12-r20pulseaudio_v12_14Nov/packages-split/pulseaudio-misc/usr/lib/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: pulseaudio-misc path '/work/sa8155-webos-linux/pulseaudio/12.0-12-r20pulseaudio_v12_14Nov/packages-split/pulseaudio-misc/usr/lib/libpulse-simple.so' [dev-so]
ERROR: pulseaudio-12.0-12-r20pulseaudio_v12_14Nov do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: pulseaudio-12.0-12-r20pulseaudio_v12_14Nov do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
```

Inorder to resolve the error
I made the following changes to the inc file. But no luck:

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so"
```

Can some one please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: maybe you have to create relative symlinks instead of using absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line solved the problem.

```
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*"
```